# Inaccessible variable within PHP

Tags: php, html, variables

Hey I am having issues with my login script. When I try access variables within the if statements it's like they are unable to be accessed it's like they are private. I have tried using PHP <kbd>$GLOBALS</kbd> to make it global but I have had no success. Here is some example code.

```
<?php
    $error = array();
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if(empty($username)){
        $error[] = 'Username can not be empty'; //This will show error
    }elseif(empty($password)){
        $error[] = 'Password can not be empty'; //This will show error
    }elseif(empty($error)){
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SOME QUERY");
        $stmt -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));
        $count = $stmt -> fetchColumn(0);
        if($count == 1){
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SOME QUERY");
        $stmt -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));
        $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if($results['status'] == 1){
                    $error[] = 'you are banned'; //This will not show error
                }
        }
    }else{
        foreach($error as $alert){
        $errors = '<p><b>example</b>' . $alert . '</p>';
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo (!empty($errors) ? $errors : ''); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's example code lol it's not something I would use.

Comment: You're too funny but thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Some places you have `$error` and some places you have `$errors`. If you have all variable references spelled the same then it should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, Tested

```
<?PHP


if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if(empty($_POST['username'])){

$error[] = 'Username Cannot Be Empty';  

}elseif(empty($_POST['password'])){

$error[] = 'Password Cannot Be Empty';  

}else{


        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password']; 

        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 16);
        $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(!empty($row['username'])){

        if($password==$row['password']){


        if($row['status']==1){

              $error[] = 'you are banned'; 

        }else{

        header("Location: index.php"); //valid login will redirect to another page

        }

        }elseif($password!=$row['password']){

        $error[] = 'Invalid Username / Password';       

        }

        }else{

        $error[] = 'Invalid Username';      

        }


}
}

?>

    <?PHP
                    //check for any errors
                    if(isset($error)){
                        foreach($error as $error){
                            echo '<p >'.$error.'</p>';
                        }
                    }

                    ?>
```

Comment: @DerekBrazil your welcome, please upvote the answer to help me out :)

Comment: I credited you in my source also I can't do that until my rep is > 15